# Contar un resultado php

Tags: php, html, php7

Con el siguiente código tengo que guardar cada vez que gano en el piedra papel o tijera, un contador donde se cuenten todas las victorias que ha tenido el humano, pero tal y como he diseñado el código se hace muy difícil comparar con victorias. He creado la variable tantoshum, pero después de muchas pruebas con diferentes prueba que se me han ocurrido no he conseguido nada en claro. Cualquier ayuda se agradece, gracias!

```
session_start();

//LOGOUT

if (isset($_POST['logout'])) {
    header('Location: ../index.php');
    return;
}

$tantoshum=0;

// Establecemos los valores del juego, 0 es piedra, 1 es papel y 2 son tijeras
$eleccion = array('Piedra', 'Papel', 'Tijera');
$humano = isset($_POST["humano"]) ? $_POST['humano'] + 0 : -1;

// rand produce un valor random, de forma que generalmos la inteligencia artificial, de la siguiente forma  $ordenador = rand(0,2);
$ordenador = rand(0, 2); 

// Esta funcion recoje el valor del ordenador y de la persona y devuelve el resultado
function check($ordenador, $humano)
{
    if (($humano == 2 && $ordenador == 0 || $humano == 0 && $ordenador == 1 || $humano == 1 && $ordenador == 2)) {
        return "Has perdido!";
    } else if ($humano == 1 && $ordenador == 0 || $humano == 0 && $ordenador == 2 || $humano == 2 && $ordenador == 1) {
        return "Has ganado!";
    } else {
        return "Empate";
    }
    return false;
}
$resultado = check($ordenador, $humano);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Daniel Vara">
    <title>Plantilla</title>
    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../estilo/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="../estilo/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../estilo/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light rounded" aria-label="Eleventh navbar example">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarsExample09" aria-controls="navbarsExample09" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample09">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
            <?php 
              $user=$_SESSION["usuario"];
              echo '<a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">usuario: '.$user.'</a>';
            ?>  
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown09" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown09">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="./eje1.php">Eje 1-3</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="./eje2.php">Eje 4-6</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="./eje3.php">Eje 7-10</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="./eje4.php">Eje 11-16</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="./eje5.php">Eje 16-21</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="./eje6.php">Eje 22-24</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ejercicio final</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-sm">
        <h1>Piedra papel o tijera</h1>
        <form method="post">
            <select name="humano">
                <option value="-1">Select</option>
                <option value="0">Piedra</option>
                <option value="1">Papel</option>
                <option value="2">Tijeras</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Jugar">
            <input type="submit" name="logout" value="Logout">
        </form>
        <?php
            if ($humano == -1) {
                print "Realizar tu eleccion";
            } else if ($humano == 3) {
                for ($c = 0; $c <= 2; $c++) {
                    for ($h = 0; $h <= 2; $h++) {
                        $r = check($c, $h);
                        print "Humano=$eleccion[$h] Ordenador=$eleccion[$c] Resultado=$r<br/>";
                    }
                }
            } else {
                echo "<div>";
                echo "<h3>Jugador 1</h3>";
                require_once '../recursos/jugada.php';
                $jugadahumano=new jugada($humano);
                
                $jugadahumano -> dibujar();
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<div>";
                echo "<h3>Jugador 2</h3>";
                $jugadaordenador=new jugada(rand(0,2));
                
                $jugadaordenador -> dibujar();
               
                echo "</div>";
                echo $resultado;
                
                echo "<div>";
                  if (isset($_REQUEST[$resultado])=='Has ganado!') {
                      $tantoshum++;
                  }
                  echo "el usuario ".$user." lleva ".$tantoshum."";
                echo "</div>";
            }
        ?>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo tienes que implementar un variable de `sesion`

```
//Sustituimos esta linea
  //$tantoshum=0;
//por esta
if(!isset($_SESSION["marcador"])) $_SESSION["marcador"] = 0;




//aumentamos el contador
var_dump($_REQUEST[$resultado]);
if (isset($_REQUEST[$resultado])) {
      if($_REQUEST[$resultado]=='Has ganado!') $_SESSION["marcador"]++;
}
 
 
 //imprimimos el resultado
 
 echo "el usuario ".$user." lleva " . $_SESSION["marcador"];
```

Comment: Si... este fue uno de mis intentos, pero no se porque el contador no progresa, y eso que tengo la sesión iniciada. El resto del programa funciona a la perfección, pero la variable se mantiene en 0

Comment: prueba el codigo. =)

Comment: Si si sigue manteniendo el resultado a 0. La variable no crece con las victorias. https://prnt.sc/1ya8ht0

Comment: puedes trazar  el resultado? es decir  al momento de  `Has ganado!`  saber si el programa esta entrando ahi ?    agregar un `var_dump("entro aqui")` he editado la respuesta

Comment: Aquí tienes el resultado: https://prnt.sc/1ya8rrl

Comment: no imprime el  `echo "entro"; `  eso que no esta entrando al ' if' por que   `true !=  "Has ganado"`  he editado la respuesta

Comment: https://prnt.sc/1yaa1qn

Answer (score 1):

Tu código no está muy entendible pero te puedo dar una idea que se me ocurre, que tal si solo comparas el numero total de la maquina versus el numero de victorias del humano pero con una sola expresión:

```
if ($ordenador > $humano) {
    echo "Gano la maquina"
} else {
    echo "Ganaste"
}
```

Recoge siempre el total y compara.

Comment: El tema es que no se como hacer para contar una victoria.

Comment: Me gusta esta solución, si quieres sumar en cada caso, puedes tener un array inicializado así: `$mData=array('humano'=>0, 'maquina'=>0);`y luego vas sumando: `if ($ordenador > $humano) { $mData['maquina']++; } else { $mData['humano']++; }` O, una solución más elegante en la cual ni siquiera haría falta un `if` sería obtener una cadena de quién ganó (que sería la clave respectiva en `$mData`) y hacer esto simplemente: `$mData[$theWinner]++;` donde `$theWinner` sería `humano` o `maquina` según el caso.